# Mesh has no vertices in Roblox studio import

Tags: mesh, error

When I import my mesh in Roblox studio the program says that it has no vertices but it does have. I tried making it a mesh but it disappears in Blender, importing it as a fbx or obj

In Blender mesh is only a curve.

Comment: You can't export a Blender curve object! Convert it to a mesh via Blender's Object > Convert > Mesh and then export it. You may need to increase the Geometry > Bevel > Depth  on the Curve object Data Properties panel slightly first to give it some thickness before converting it to a mesh.